# Artifact version search not working with exact version

Tags: artifactory, artifactory-query-lang

Artifactory 6.9.1

The artifact existing in the Artifactory is shown below:
[image]

I am using the following query based on the REST API doc. for [artifact version search](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-ArtifactVersionSearch):

```
curl --request GET "https://repository.net/artifactory/api/search/versions?g=com.name&a=core-api-error&repos=core-services&v=0.4.0-56204b7*"

    {
      "results" : [ {
        "version" : "0.4.0-56204b7",
        "integration" : false
      } ]
    }
```

but if I try to use the exact version by removing '*' from the 'v' argument,

```
curl --request GET "https://repository.name.net/artifactory/api/search/versions?g=com.name&a=core-api-error&repos=core-services&v=0.4.0-56204b7"
{
  "errors" : [ {
    "status" : 404,
    "message" : "Unable to find artifact versions"
  } ]
}
```

The usage of '*' is dangerous as it might return some other versions. I just want to check if the artifact with that version exists.